# Strange runtime for data flows implementing the same Azure IR

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My scenario is this: I have two Pipelines. Each one of them has two dataflows, and the four use the same IR.
I have triggered the pipeline number one. Its first dataflow took around four minutes to start the cluster. As soon as this dataflow finished, I triggered the second pipe.  However, its first dataflow took once again almost 5 minutes to acquire the resources. But I was expecting it to use the pool that it was already available like the second dataflow did in the first pipeline.

[image]

Is there something that I'm not considering?

Comment: Open the detail monitoring view for the data flows using the eyeglasses icon. In the top-right of the display you'll see a "cluster start up time". That will tell you whether ADF was able to reuse existing VMs in your Databricks pool. If the time is 3-4 mins, it had to form a cluster from a new VM. If the time was <2 mins, then Databricks used an existing warm VM.

Comment: Hi @MarkKromer thanks a lot for always reply to my doubts. That is what happened: the first dataflow of the second pipeline took 4m 18 sec to acquire the resources. So, my question is, why this dataflow was not able to use the warm VM created in the other pipeline considering that all of them have the same IR? Is this common? For us, this is very important because we are preparing a proposal for our client analyzing not only time but also costs, and it is necessary to have the answer for all the possible questions they could have.

Comment: That's because you started that 2nd pipeline while the last data flow activity was still executing. TTL and warm pools are meant for sequential execution. Databricks job clusters use a "single job" isolation methodology. So, you tried to execute 2 jobs at the same time to the same cluster and Databricks said "nope". ADF won't fail that 2nd job and instead spun-up a 2nd pool, which is why you had to wait 4 mins for that new VM pool to form.

Comment: Just ensure that you schedule the next pipeline after the previous activity completes. BTW, we are adding controls to the Azure IR for this exact case with optional queuing and max concurrency settings very soon, so it will make for a better experience for you.

Comment: @MarkKromer great to hear about it. And thanks again for your help.

Comment: @d2907 do you have any other concerns? Maybe we can summary the comments and post an answer.

Comment: Hi @LeonYue thanks for your reply. The last concern about this topic is how to choose the right configuration for my IR, what are those variables that I need to consider when selecting for example the number of Cores or the compute type.